# I do not really get the full joke from a video clip

Tags: meaning-in-context

Who was in fact the woman in the image below?

Was she a (Russian) prostitute or agent sent by Vasily Valishnikov or a character in an (unfinished) screenplay written by that man exasperated by her negligence or something else? I am especially not clear about the meaning of the last line.

[image: Foreplay]

[See the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXISA9YHGoI)

I watched the video a few times and finally this is what I understood:
(I mention that I usually barely understand the dialog in a movie in English.)

Man: [You was so sexy.]

Man: What the f**k are you doing?

Woman: What?

Man: That was my favorite shirt. You just popped all the buttons of my favorite shirt. I am not going to be able to find those buttons. I heard one land way over there. You do realize a buttoned up shirt is function-less without buttons. Right?

Woman: Sorry, just [.....] a moment, I guess.

Man: It is all right.

Man: Wait, wait.

Man: Oh, there is a problem.

Woman: What, what did I do.

Man: That was my screenplay. [....], now it is [....] the border. I am missing page 79. Do you have any idea how long did I spend on page 79? That was the end of act two.

Woman: [....] sure to [....] somewhere?

Man: You know, forget it. It was a try concept anyway.

Woman: Listen, I am going to go.

Man: No, no, no, do not go. It is collateral damage, it happens. Let's just make our way to the bedroom.

Man: My lamp. My door now.

Man: Be careful in here. For the last two years I have been playing chess with the Russian grand-master Vasily Valishnikov and I am one move away from check mate.

Woman: Call me.

Woman: Vasily, it is done [dawn].

Vasily: He was two moves away from beating. What about the screenplay.

Woman: You would not believe the twisted up [turn].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who was the woman? Someone working for Vasily Valishnikov.

The assumption is that Vasily sent her to disrupt the chess game. But the last line shows that he also wanted that page 79 from the man's screenplay.

As soon as we hear her Russian accent and speak to Vasily, we know why she was there. But the last line makes it extra funny because the screenplay is an unexpected target.

I've also edited your script of the video, corrections in bold:

> Man: You are so sexy.
>   *(Woman rips shirt open)*
>
> Man: What the f**k are you doing?
>   Woman: What?
>
> Man: That was my favorite shirt. You just popped all the buttons **off** my favorite shirt. I am not going to be able to find those buttons. I heard one land way over there. You do realize a buttoned-up shirt is function-less without buttons. Right?
>
> Woman: Sorry, **just heat of the moment**, I guess.
>   Man: It is all right.
>
> Man: Wait, wait.
>   *(Woman clears the man's desk)**
>   Man: Oh, **what is your problem?**
>   Woman: What, what did I do.
>
> Man: That was my screenplay. **Oh great, now it's all out of order**.
>   I am missing page 79. Do you have any idea **how long I spent** on
>   page 79? That was the end of act two.
>
> Woman: **I'm sure it's around here** somewhere?
>   Man: You know, forget it. It was a **trite** concept anyway.
>   Woman: Listen, I am going to go.
>   Man: No, no, no, do not go. It was collateral damage, it happens. Let's just make our way to the bedroom.
>
> *(breaks lamp)*
>   Man: My lamp!
>   *(breaks doorknob)*
>   Man: My **doorknob**!
>   *(enters bedroom)*
>   Man: Be careful in here. For the last two years I have been playing chess with the Russian grand-master Vasily Valishnikov and I am one move away from check...
>   *(Woman tosses shoe and breaks the chess board setup)*
>   Man: ...mate.
>
> *(Man sees the woman out of his apartment and slams the door)*
>   Woman: Call me.
>
> *(Woman makes a phone call)*
>   Woman: Vasily, it is done.
>   Vasily: **Good.** He was two moves away from beating me. What about the screenplay?
>
> Woman: You would not believe the **twist in Act Two**.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be *all the buttons **off** my favorite shirt*?

Comment: Thank you for the corrected text and your explanations.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I listened to it again and you're right, he says, "off". Thanks.

Comment: Another mistake I made was "how long did I spend". It should be "how long I spent".

Comment: @RobertWerner Good catch. Fixed that as well.

Comment: The twist is the moment when the woman says "Vasily, it is done". This is an unexpected thing. Had the video finished immediately after Vasily replied "Good. He was two moves away from beating me." the joke would have been perfectly logical. However, we find out from what the woman says that the screenplay had also a twist. This is a strange coincidence.